# iPhone X UITableViewController with a fixed bottom bar display the table content below opaque toolbar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitoolbar, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I want to make a UITableViewController with a fixed bottom bar. So I made this with these codes.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    saveButton.size = CGSize(width: self.view.width, height: 50)
    saveButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    saveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveContactsInfo), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    let btn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveContactsInfo))
    let fixspace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    fixspace.width = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.items = [fixspace, btn, fixspace]

    self.navigationController?.toolbar.addSubview(saveButton)

 self.navigationController?.toolbar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: saveButton.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: saveButton.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: saveButton.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: saveButton.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.clipsToBounds = true
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: UIColor.white), forToolbarPosition: .bottom, barMetrics: .default)

}
```

The bottom bar display as I wish but the table view was shown below the bottom bar. Like this:

[image]

I tried uncheck Under Bottom Bars but it's not work well.

[image]

I just want the area below the bottom bar be white. How to make this display correct?

Comment: Hi, @鸡肉味嘎嘣脆, did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: @Leandro No, not yet. Adding UITableView to UIViewController could make it looks right. But for UITableViewController I haven't found a solution.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I think I will refactor this view. Good luck!